# How extract data from html using php

Tags: php, html

I have fetch this html code.

```
<td valign="top" style="padding:3px">

    <p>

    <b>Release Year: </b>2005

    <br />

    <b>
    Genre: 
    <a href=/genres/Animation>Animation</a>, 
    <a href=/genres/Comedy>Comedy</a>
    </b>

    <br />

    <b>External Links: </b> 
    <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0397306/" target="_blank">IMDB</a> 
    <br />

    <b>No. of episodes: </b> 23 episodes 

    <br />

    <b>Latest Episode With Links: </b> 

    <a title="Watch American Dad! Latest Episode (American Dad! Season 1 Episode 23)" href="/episode/american_dad_s1_e23.html">
    Season 1 Episode 23 Tears of a Clooney (14/05/2006)
    </a>

    <br />

    <div style="float: left; height: 30px; overflow: hidden; width: 100px;">

    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://watchseries.ag/season-1/american_dad" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div>

    </div>

    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://watchseries.ag/season-1/american_dad">Tweet</a>

    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

    <br clear="all" />

    <b>Description :</b> The random escapades of Stan Smith, an extreme right wing CIA agent dealing with family life and keeping America safe, all in the most absurd way possible.<br>

    </p>
    </td>
```

I want only this information from above html code using php.

Only want 3 things
**1.Release Year
2. Imdb Link
3. Genre**

```
array(
     'release_year'=>2005, 
     'imbd_link'=>'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0397306/',
     'genre'=> array(
                     'Animation',
                     'Comedy',
                    )
     );
```

I have also created php function which filter html code and return me array but its not give the result like above i showed the array() its give me this result

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [release year] => 2005Genre
)
```

**function**

```
function do_html_array($td,$dlm='<br>'){
    if(!empty($td)){
        $td = html_entity_decode($td);
        $td = preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $td);
        $html_array = explode($dlm,$td);
        $html_key_array = array();
        foreach($html_array as $key=>$html){
                $html = explode(':',trim(strip_tags($html)));
                if(trim($html[0])!=''){
                    if(count($html)<1) $html[1] = '';                   
                    if(strtolower(trim($html[0]))=='description') $html[1] = str_ireplace('[+]more','',$html[1]);
                    $html_key_array[strtolower(trim($html[0]))] = trim($html[1]);
                    switch(trim(strtolower($html[0]))){
                        case'external links':
                             preg_match_all('~<a\s+.*?</a>~is',$html_array[$key],$html_key_array['imdb_link']);                          
                        break;
                        case'genre':
                             preg_match_all('~<a\s+.*?</a>~is',$html_array[$key],$html_key_array['genre_link']);                             
                        break;
                        // further define here...
                    }
                }
        }
        return $html_key_array;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: And what error would that be?

Comment: As @Bulk already asked, what error? Show us, what is error message if there is any. If not, then tell us what happens, and why it's not what you want to happen.

Comment: Use some standard parser like PHP DOM parser which makes your parsing easy. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanks for all your response i have edited my question and show which i have get from this php function and Makesh i am already using simple html dom. Please help thank you